# IDataReader - Get value of SQL time(7) field to use in calculations

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, time, datareader

Using IDataReader, I need to get time values so that I can get the timespan.  In my SQL database, these values are time(7).  I am getting an error - InvalidCast Exception was unhandled by user code.  Here is my code (and I know I have to rewrite the Select statement):

```
commandvct.CommandText = "Select begindateoff, enddateoff, begintimeoff, endtimeoff, allday_yesno from tblworkhours where Employee = " & rve & " and workcode = 2"
commandvct.CommandType = CommandType.Text
commandvct.Connection = sqlConnection

sqlConnection.Open()

Using reader As IDataReader = commandvct.ExecuteReader

    While reader.Read()

        Dim begdate As Date = reader.GetDateTime(0)
        Dim enddate As Date = reader.GetDateTime(1)

        If begdate = enddate Then

            Dim allday As Boolean = reader.GetBoolean(4)

            'If all day, add 8 hours
            If (allday = True) Then

                workinghoursv = workinghoursv + 8 'Change me to your needs.
                TextBoxva2.Text = workinghoursv

                'If not all day, add difference between times
            Else
            'tried defining it as datetime and as string - neither work
                Dim begtime As String = reader.GetDateTime(2)
                Dim endtime As DateTime = reader.GetDateTime(3)

                Dim diffv As TimeSpan = (endtime).Subtract(begtime)
                Dim diff2v As Decimal = (Convert.ToDecimal(diffv.TotalMinutes)) / 60
                workinghoursv = workinghoursv + diff2v
                TextBoxva2.Text = workinghoursv


            End If
```

Comment: `Dim begtime As String = reader.GetDateTime(2)` you are trying to get a DateTime type and store it in a string.  If the db has it as a Date get it into a Date type like in the line after that

Comment: You were quick!  I edited my post saying I tried it as both DateTime and String.  Neither work.

Comment: there is more to the error msg but you did not share it. what is the column type for begintimeoff and endtimeoff?

Comment: This code is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: Begintimeoff and endtimeoff are time(7) in my SQL Database.  Joel - Thanks for pointing this out.  I know I have to re-write it.  Right now, it's an internal web program only accessible to my department.  Since it may be used in other depts, I'm going to read about fixing this.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Plutonix - Besides, the Invalid Cast Exception was unhandled by user code, it says Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: if it is SQL Server, use a SqlDataReader then you can use `GetTimeSpan`  or `reader("begintimeoff")` and cast it.  beware of DBNull though

Comment: Plutonix - You rock!  Tried both ways and both worked.  How do we mark it as an answer so you get credit?